# IP blocking and TLS v1.3's Encrypted SNI

Tags: tls, network

It is my understanding that TLS's version 1.3 would prevent censors or any other middlebox entity from knowing the SNI field and hence know what is traveling on the network, or which particular websites the users are trying to access. However, I was wondering why was this considered as something important to introduce when IP blocking is something that can still be done by mapping websites to IP addresses. I understand that the IP addresses that users direct their requests towards may not be direct domain IP addresses but could instead correspond to entities like CDNs, but I was wondering how much of an information would be lost for the censors if all internet traffic would switch to TLS version 1.3

Comment: Encrypted SNI is not part of TLS 1.3. It will be a separate standard (currently only draft).

Comment: Ah okay. I am still curious the dynamics of what it enables or does not enable to do versus the still-available possibility of IP blocking.